# Using variable as Jenkins input message text

Tags: shell, jenkins, input, jenkins-pipeline

i would like to use a variable as a message inside an input step inside a scripted pipeline.

```
stage("Manual Approval"){
        sh """
        ls -la
        versionNumber=`grep -wE -A 2 '"package": "example0"'`
        ancestorVersion=`grep -wE -A 2 '"package": "example"'`
        """
        timeout(time: 120, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            input message: "Do you want to build ver. ${versionNumber} having ver. ${ancestorVersion} as an ancestor?", submitter: 'user1'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of the pipeline `sh` step allows save the output in a variable, following:

```
script {
    INFO_SYSTEM = sh (
        script: 'uname -a',
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()
    echo "Value: ${INFO_SYSTEM}"
}
```

Output:

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/testing
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Testing)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ uname -a
[Pipeline] echo
Value: Linux d7d184735414 4.14.225-121.357.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 15 23:52:05 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

So, maybe you can change the approach for do this task getting each variable in executing in a single command and retrieve the output, like this:

```
stage("Manual Approval"){
    VERSION_NUMBER = sh (
            script: 'grep -wE -A 2 '"package": "example0"'',
            returnStdout: true
        ).trim()

    ANCESTOR_VERSION = sh (
            script: 'grep -wE -A 2 '"package": "example"'',
            returnStdout: true
        ).trim()

    timeout(time: 120, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            input message: "Do you want to build ver. ${VERSION_NUMBER} having ver. ${ANCESTOR_VERSION} as an ancestor?", submitter: 'user1'
        }
}
```